# Rails devise undefined method `after_sign_in_path_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :js
  layout false

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)

    if resource && resource.active_for_authentication?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    end
  end

end
```

and my template for it

create.js.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in?%>
  <%= after_sign_in_path_for(resource) %>
<% else %>
 Erorrs here...
  })
<% end %>
```

I want redirect to specific page after sign in but have got

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `after_sign_in_path_for' for #<#<Class
```

what should i do to fix it?

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks",:confirmations => "confirmations",:passwords => "passwords", :sessions => "sessions" }
  end
```

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy  added routes

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar implementation can you try this

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]

    def create
      self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)

      if resource && resource.active_for_authentication?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      end

      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
end
```

In `ApplicationController`

```
private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
  end
```